# Azure Cosmos DB .NET Bulk Executor response shows fewer documents imported than actually appear in Cosmos

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**Goal**

To import >1 million documents into Azure Cosmos DB using C#, .NET Core 2.2.

**What I have tried**

I am using the Azure Cosmos Bulk Executor library. I am following the sample here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net, e.g.

```cs
// Set retry options high during initialization (default values).
client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30;
client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 9;

IBulkExecutor bulkExecutor = new BulkExecutor(client, dataCollection);
await bulkExecutor.InitializeAsync();

// Set retries to 0 to pass complete control to bulk executor.
client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 0;
client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 0;
```

Next I run

```cs
var bulkImportResponse = await bulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync(documents, true);
if ((bulkImportResponse.NumberOfDocumentsImported < documents.Count) ||
    (bulkImportResponse.BadInputDocuments?.Count > 0))
{
    // Logging, exception throwing, etc.
}
```

**The problem**

I have run the import several times for the same source data.

- Following the import, the Cosmos collection has the correct number of documents (namely 1237278).
- However, `bulkImportResponse.NumberOfDocumentsImported` is often (but not always) less than this by around a thousand or 0.1%. E.g. last run it was 1236175. `bulkImportResponse.BadInputDocuments` is always null.

**Questions**

Q1: Does anyone know whether something has gone wrong with import, or whether it is just the `bulkImportResponse.NumberOfDocumentsImported` value which is incorrect.

Q2: If there is something wrong with these 1000 documents, is there any way to get logs of which documents might be wrong. No messages are written during the imports above - I've looked through the source code for `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.BulkExecutor`, but don't see anything which provides anything extra.

**Properties of the documents and target**

- The target Cosmos collection is empty before starting.
- I have created Cosmos with the SQL-API.
- `documents` has 1237278 objects.
- Every document has values both for the `id` field, and for the field that is used as the partition key.
- In total there will be 4501 partitions.
- The documents are shuffled before the import to maximise the throughput by writing to as many different partitions as possible simultaneously (as described here - https://medium.com/@jayanta.mondal/azure-cosmos-db-bulk-import-tool-realizing-the-full-potential-722bb4f98476).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add which version of the Bulk Executor library are you using? Are you on the latest (1.8.5)?

Comment: v2.3.0-preview2 - (I'm using .NET Core v2.2)

Comment: Which is your Consistency in the account? (btw, for NET Core 2.4.1-preview seems to be the last one, have you tried that one?)

Answer (score 0):

Not able to reproduce your issue. Here are some personal suggestions:

1. You may divide the documents into smaller collections. And then run multiple tasks, and finally combine results together.
2. To verify if all the documents were imported, you may check the total document number by `SELECT VALUE Count(1) from c`. Then you will get the real number of imported documents.  Basically, if the number is right, all the documents should be OK. You can also compare each document on the cloud with local.
3. For these kind of SDK issue, as it is partially successful and there is no error, it is hard to identify the root cause. A better approach is to open an issue on [its](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started) Github project. The project contributors may help you further.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the suggestions. `SELECT VALUE Count(1) from c` gives a value equal to the right number, but I've not done a compare yet.